# Standard way to detect form values has been changed?

Tags: javascript

I need to detect the value changes in from before refreshing page or closing page , i have written function which will trim the form value and concatenate to previous value

```
function formValue(object) {
        var formValue = "";
        $(object).find("input,select,radio,checkbox,textarea").each(function(){        
            formValue += $(this).val().trim() + "&";
        });
        return formValue.substring(0, formValue.length - 1);
    }
}
```

i will store the value in `oldValue` variable on page old.On `unloadEvent` it will compare old value with new form value

```
var addEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
var unloadEvent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload';

addEvent(unloadEvent, function (e) {

    if(oldvalue!==formValue($("form")){
    retun "Data will lost , Do you wish to continue ?"
    }
});
```

it is working great , But i have doubt that , **Is this standard way** to check form value changed or **any other best way is available** to detect form value changes ?

***I need to stop page reload or exit only if value has been changed . i mean if i change the input box value from name to first name and again changes it name . now it should not treat as from value change***

Comment: are you using jQuery??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check form data change or not form more reliable way, it's also easy

```
var formChangeFlag = false;
$('form').on('change', ':input', function(e){ 
 //':input' selector get all form fields even textarea, input, or select
  formChangeFlag = true;
});

$( window ).unload(function() {
  if(formChangeFlag === true){
     return "Data will lost , Do you wish to continue ?";
   }
});
```

**Update on comment:** If you want to compare form data with default value then store default form value in `data-*` attribute and compare value on field change event.

```js
var formChangeFlag = false;
_$Forminputs = $('form :input:not([type=submit])');
_$Forminputs.on('change', function(e) {
  //':input' selector get all form fields even textarea, input, or select
  formChangeFlag = false;
  //alert(_$Forminputs.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < _$Forminputs.length; i++) {
    if ($(_$Forminputs[i]).val() != $(_$Forminputs[i]).data('default')) {
      formChangeFlag = true;
      break;
    }
  }
});

$('input[type=submit]').on('click', function() {
  if (formChangeFlag === true) {
    alert('form values changed')
  } else {
    alert('form values not changed')
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" type="post">
  <select name="sirnmae" data-default="Mr.">
    <option value="Mr." selected>Mr.</option>
    <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" data-default="ger" value="ger" name="fname" />
  <input type="text" value="last name" data-default="last name" />
  <input type="submit" value="post form" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi , need to know only value has been changed, if i enter some text and then delete that text what will happen , it also considered as change right?

Comment: Yes it will also consider that.. do you want to compare with default value??

Comment: but it should consider it as change. Example
 name-->firstname and again firstname-->name , it is not change right ?

Comment: see updated answer, you can also check form value change or not on `unload` event

Comment: @Mahendran see this demo https://jsfiddle.net/pmLt5d9p/5/ this is working, there `data-default` and `value` attribute values were not same..

Comment: This is not working , first edit value ger and submit it show alert value changed, now edit value last name  and submit now it show value changed now rever value of first text box to default value and submit it show value not changed bit value of second text box has been changed.

Comment: ok got it, i was not noticed this issue, see this https://jsfiddle.net/pmLt5d9p/8/ hope it would works for you

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the *defaultValue* with the current *value* of all form controls. The only difficulty is select elements, for those you can check if the selected index is -1 (no option selected), 0 (first option selected, the default in nearly every browser) or that the selected option has the *selected* attribute.

The following does that:

```
function formChanged(form) {
  return [].every.call(form.elements, function(control) {

    // If a select's selected index is -1 (no option selected),
    // 0 (first option selected) or set to an option that is
    // selected by default, it hasn't changed
    if (control.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'select') {
      var idx = control.selectedIndex;
      return idx == -1 || idx == 0 || control.options[idx].defaultSelected;
    }

    // Otherwise, check current value with default value
    return control.value == control.defaultValue;
  });
}
```

It won't work for a multiple select that has more than one option set to selected by default (pretty rare), but will work everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

There is a onchange() function which returns the value once the user leaves the input box. This works for several HTML elements. Simply grab the value from the element ex:

```
<input type="text" onchange="newVar=this.value"/>
```

Or register an event listener. This should complete your task easily.

Comment: if i enter some value and remove that value it also consider as form change but i should not consider as from change. because by form value look same old one , right ?

Comment: If the user changes it AT ALL, when they are finished editing, it will give you the new value.

Comment: You probably need to see the old value and compare it to make sure it has changed.